# MySQL syntax error using MySqlCommand in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Below I have the SQL query which I have tested is working fine

```
Select 
    data_info.user_id, data_info.type_id, data_info.specific_title,
    data_info.content, life_area.type_id, life_area.type_id
From
    data_info 
Left Join
    life_area On data_info.type_id = life_area.id
Where 
    data_info.user_id = '0001'
```

Now I am trying to convert the working SQL into asp.net `MySqlCommand`, but it fails to work and show syntax error

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    "Select data_info.user_id,data_info.type_id,data_info.specific_title,data_info.content,"+
    "life_area.type_id,life_area.type_id" +
    "FROM data_info LEFT JOIN life_area ON data_info.type_id = life_area.id" +
    "Where data_info.user_id='0001'" , conn);
```

Comment: Print out the SQL string from your code, and look at it closely, especially stuff like missing comas or spaces.

Comment: I dont see spaces between strings, like this `... area.type_id" (space?) + "FROM ...`

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space between the end of the select list and the `FROM` for starters.  I'd suggest creating a verbatim string instead (put a '@' before it) so you can include line breaks instead of the concatenation mess you currently have.  Also in the future you really should include the error message you get.

Comment: @juharr, since i m just starting to learn asp.net , care to explain a little bit more, thanks

Comment: @epiphany Well specifically your query is "... life_area.type_idFROM ..." because your second string does not end  with a space and your third does not start with one.  If you put a `@` before the string it allows it to span multiple lines and it is called a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)  Also you got an error message when you tried to run this code, you should always include error messages in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re combining the strings together without spaces in crucial areas, e.g. `life_area.type_id' + 'FROM data_info'` gives you `life_area.type_idFROM data_info`; this is making your SQL invalid. Using a `@`([verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)) string to honour the carriage returns is likely the best solution:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    @"Select data_info.user_id,data_info.type_id,data_info.specific_title,data_info.content,
    life_area.type_id,life_area.type_id
    FROM data_info LEFT JOIN life_area ON data_info.type_id = life_area.id 
    Where data_info.user_id='0001'" , conn);
```

Comment: It's actually called a verbatim string or verbatim string literal.  String literal means something else by itself.